# How to test reactive APIs in Quarkus using RestAssured

Tags: java, junit, quarkus, smallrye, quarkus-reactive

I have Quarkus app and I am trying to test my reactive Controller REST APIs using RestAssured.

And I am using [smallrye-mutiny](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/1.6.0/tutorials/creating-uni-pipelines) for developing my REST APIs.

**The issue is when running the test RestAssured is trying to serialize the Uni and it throwing the following exception saying it could not found a serializer for Uni type. :**

```
Caused by:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of 
`io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either 
need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type 
information

at [Source: (String) 
{   
   "header":{
      "statusCode":"99-9999",
      "statusDescription":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)"    
    } 
} 
; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Here is how my code looks like:

My Service Layer:

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
@ApplicationScoped
public class AccountOpeningServiceImpl implements AccountOpeningService {


@Override
public Uni<GetRandomNumberResponseApi> getRandomNumber(GetRandomNumberRequestApi requestApi) {
   Uni<GetRandomNumberResponseApi> numberUni = Uni.createFrom().item(() -> GetRandomNumberResponseApi.builder().number(10).build()))
   return numberUni;
}
```

My Controller :

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;    
@Path("")
public class AccountOpeningController {

@Inject
AccountOpeningService accountOpeningService;

@POST
@Path("/random-number")
public Uni<GetRandomNumberResponseApi> getRandomNumber(@Valid GetRandomNumberRequestApi requestApi) {
    return accountOpeningService.getRandomNumber(requestApi);
}
```

And finally here is my test how it looks like.

```
@QuarkusTest
public class AccountOpeningControllerTest {

@InjectMock
AccountOpeningService accountOpeningService;

@Inject
MockUtil mockUtil;

@Test
void getRandomNumber() throws IOException {
    GetRandomNumberRequestApi requestApi = mockUtil.getMock("Get_Random_Number_Request.json",
            GetRandomNumberRequestApi.class);

    GetRandomNumberResponseApi responseApi = mockUtil.getMock("Get_Random_Number_Response.json",
            GetRandomNumberResponseApi.class);
    when(accountOpeningService.getRandomNumber(requestApi)).thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(responseApi));

    Uni<GetRandomNumberResponseApi> response = given()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(requestApi)
            .when()
            .post("/get-random-number")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .as(new TypeRef<Uni<GetRandomNumberResponseApi>>() {
            });
    
    GetRandomNumberResponseApi actualResponse = response.subscribe()
            .withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create())
            .assertCompleted()
            .getItem();
    Assertions.assertEquals(responseApi, actualResponse);
}
```

Any help, advices, resources?

Comment: Don't try to extract a `Uni` from the response. It is a plain old HTTP response with a plain old JSON body. Forget about the `Uni` on the RestAssured side and write the test synchronously.

Comment: Yes I tried this as well here is the answer that followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/72920056/7137509
but still it's having the same issue because Rest Assured is trying to desrialize the response on either ways then it is returning it.

Comment: +100 to what @Ladicek proposes

Comment: @geoand Yes I tried what he is suggesting but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

That's because RestAssured tries to serialize a mock object. That mock object has extra properties like `mockitoInterceptor` and so on. And one or more of those properties in the tree are not serializable by Jackson.

So use real objects as request body and as expected response.

The following test will work

```java
@QuarkusTest
class ExampleResourceTest {

    @InjectMock
    RandomNumberService service;

    @Test
    void testRandomNumberEndpoint() {

        // create a real (not mocked) request object
        var request = new RandomNumberRequestDTO();
        request.setUpper(500L);
        request.setLower(3L);

        // create a real (not mocked) response object
        var expectedResponse = new RandomNumberResponseDTO(3L, 500L, 399L);

        // mock service with real request and response object
        Mockito.when(service.getRandomNumber(request)) //pass real request object
                .thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(expectedResponse)); // pass real response object

        var resp =
                given()
                    .when()
                        .body(request) // pass real request object
                        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                        .post("/random-number")
                    .then()
                        .statusCode(200)
                        .extract()
                        .as(RandomNumberResponseDTO.class);
        assertAll(
                () -> assertNotNull(resp),
                () -> assertEquals(request.getLower(), resp.getLower()),
                () -> assertEquals(request.getUpper(), resp.getUpper()),
                () -> assertThat(resp.getRandomNumber(), is(both(greaterThanOrEqualTo(resp.getLower())).and(lessThan(resp.getUpper()))))
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Well still it's throwing the same exception and the serializer kicks in again to serialize the `Uni<GetRandomNumberResponseApi>`

Answer (score 0):

After 18 hours of searching
I came to know that I need to add `quarkus-resteasy-mutiny` to my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-mutiny</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

I think this dependency contains the Uni serializer by default.

Comment: Really? Forgot to mention you are using `RestEasy Classic` instead of `RestEasy Reactive`.